# How to set radio button checked as default in radiogroup?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have created  `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton` dynamically as following:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
                    RadioButton radioBtn1 = new RadioButton(context);
                    RadioButton radioBtn2 = new RadioButton(context);
                    RadioButton radioBtn3 = new RadioButton(context);

                    radioBtn1.setText("Less");
                    radioBtn2.setText("Normal");
                    radioBtn3.setText("More");

                    radioBtn2.setChecked(true);

                    radioGroup.addView(radioBtn1);
                    radioGroup.addView(radioBtn2);
                    radioGroup.addView(radioBtn3);
```

Here step `radioBtn2.setChecked(true);` causes `radioBtn2` always checked. That means I cannot uncheck `radioBtn2` by checking other two radio buttons (`radioBtn1`,`radioBtn3`). I want to make that `RadioGroup` can check only one radio button at a time (Now it can check two radiobutton at a time).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is there you need dynamically???

Answer (score 261, accepted):

you should check the radiobutton in the radiogroup like this:

`radiogroup.check(IdOfYourButton)`

Of course you first have to set an Id to your radiobuttons

EDIT: i forgot, `radioButton.getId()` works as well, thx Ramesh

EDIT2:

```xml
android:checkedButton="@+id/my_radiobtn"
```

works in radiogroup xml

Comment: or if you don't want to id your `RadioButton` and you know the index you can use **((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(INDEX)).setChecked(true);**

Comment: You shouldn't do that. That will cause the "setChecked" problem described in this question. Of course there are ways to do that without ids of your buttons, but please not by using `setChecked()`

One way would be `radiogroup.check(((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(INDEX)).getId())` or something like that

Comment: good to not forget to add the radio button to the radio button group _before_ calling group.check(button.getId())

Comment: I had to do it this way: `radioGroup.Check(radioGroup.GetChildAt(0).Id);` for Xamarin.Android users

Answer (score 118):

In case for xml attribute its `android:checkedButton` which takes the `id` of the `RadioButton` to be checked.

```
<RadioGroup
...
...
android:checkedButton="@+id/IdOfTheRadioButtonInsideThatTobeChecked"
... >....</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 62):

In the XML file set the `android:checkedButton` field in your `RadioGroup`, with the id of your default `RadioButton`:

```
<RadioGroup
    ....
    android:checkedButton="@+id/button_1">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        ...../>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        ...../>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        ...../>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 20):

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(WvActivity.this);
    RadioButton radioBtn1 = new RadioButton(this);
    RadioButton radioBtn2 = new RadioButton(this);
    RadioButton radioBtn3 = new RadioButton(this);

    radioBtn1.setText("Less");
    radioBtn2.setText("Normal");
    radioBtn3.setText("More");


    radioGroup.addView(radioBtn1);
    radioGroup.addView(radioBtn2);
    radioGroup.addView(radioBtn3);

    radioGroup.check(radioBtn2.getId());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
RadioButton radioBtn1 = new RadioButton(context);
RadioButton radioBtn2 = new RadioButton(context);
RadioButton radioBtn3 = new RadioButton(context);

radioBtn1.setText("Less");
radioBtn2.setText("Normal");
radioBtn3.setText("More");

radioGroup.addView(radioBtn1);
radioGroup.addView(radioBtn2);
radioGroup.addView(radioBtn3);
radioBtn2.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: The important thing is to use `setChecked()` after all radio buttons have been added to the radio group. Then, `radioGroup.check(radioBtn2.getId())` is not neccessary

Answer (score 3):

There was same problem in my Colleague's code. This sounds as your Radio Group is not properly set with your Radio Buttons. This is the reason you can multi-select the radio buttons. I tried many things, finally i did a trick which is wrong actually, but works fine.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < myCount ; i++ )
{
    if ( i != k )
    {
        System.out.println ( "i = " + i );
        radio1[i].setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

Here I set one for loop, which checks for the available radio buttons and de-selects every one except the new clicked one. try it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of RadioGroup

```
RadioButton radioBtn2 = new RadioButton(context);
```

radioBtn2 without viewId, and generateViewId is in onChildViewAdded()

```
public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
    if (parent == RadioGroup.this && child instanceof RadioButton) {
        int id = child.getId();
        // generates an id if it's missing
        if (id == View.NO_ID) {
            id = View.generateViewId();
            child.setId(id);
        }
        ((RadioButton) child).setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener(
                mChildOnCheckedChangeListener);
    }

    if (mOnHierarchyChangeListener != null) {
        mOnHierarchyChangeListener.onChildViewAdded(parent, child);
    }
}
```

so, first radioGroup.addView(radioBtn2), then radioBtn2.setChecked(true);

Like this:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
RadioButton radioBtn1 = new RadioButton(context);
RadioButton radioBtn2 = new RadioButton(context);
RadioButton radioBtn3 = new RadioButton(context);

radioBtn1.setText("Less");
radioBtn2.setText("Normal");
radioBtn3.setText("More");

radioGroup.addView(radioBtn1);
radioGroup.addView(radioBtn2);
radioGroup.addView(radioBtn3);

radioBtn2.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:checked = "true"` in your activity.xml

Comment: This should be added to <RadioButton> tag, since this is an important detail!