# radio button auto select when page load in android

Tags: android

There are two activities as A and B. There is two radio buttons as radio1 & radio2 on page B. when load B page after click button of A page first radio button need to view as checked/clicked .

Comment: in your xml add android:checked=true to whichever radio button you want to be checked

Comment: radio1.setChecked(true); will also work if done from java

Comment: You need learn more bcz it is very simple , please find solution yourself.

Comment: i already add android:checked = true. but its show radio button selected only in xml layout of android studio. not showing when run the app in emulator or real device.#nishant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set radio button checked as default in radiogroup with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175635/how-to-set-radio-button-checked-as-default-in-radiogroup-with-android)

Answer (score 2):

In your XML file, you can set the following attribute on the radio button you want selected: `android:checked="true"`

Or programmatically, you can select the radio button by using the following method written in your onCreate:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
radioButton.setChecked(true);
```